is there any specific way to convert a country's gdp to us dollars?
I need to convert Indonesia's real/constant GDP(rupiah) base year 2010 to USD. is it like basic convert using exchange rate based on the year I look for? or is there other way?
I am concerned with the reason i use constant GDP to adjust the inflation, but using exchange rate that is impacted by the inflation would be wrong? guide me please, thank you.

https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/52599/37817 should help. For short, just use FX rate of the period you look at. After all, if you wanted to know what something costs in USD, that's the rate you need and what an actual transaction would have used.
